# Is there a way to handle messages directly from the Rebus error queue

Tags: rabbitmq, rebus

Currently I have an IErrorHandler implementation dealing with messages going to the Rebus error queue. That handler then publishes messages to a saga that throttles output to a Slack notification channel. I think there may be an easier way to do this though. I would like to have the saga implement an IHandleMessages against messages from the Rebus error queue itself. Is that possible? Currently, we have the FleetManager process enabled and for my custom IErrorHandler to work it has to dual publish errors both to the error queue and to FleetManager using the FleetManager API options. This allows my IErrorHandler to be called so I can publish a custom message to start the slack saga and also feeds FleetManager with the data it needs. The problem with my approach is that the Rebus error queue just grows with data I no longer care about. So I guess my question is: is there a way to handle those Rebus error queue messages? Or perhaps even better, is there a simple way to make those error queue messages go away once I know I have them in my saga?

Note: the reason for the saga and to not simply use a FleetManager Slack web hook is to notify based on custom count thresholds of errors, rather than for every error encountered.

Answer (score 0):

I think I just realized one approach I could take, which is to still use my custom IErrorHandler, yet not actually handle the poison message so that it never makes it to the error queue regardless. Instead I would just publish my custom message that is handled by the saga.